# Print statement in function not working

Tags: python, printing, function

I am trying to define a function which calculates the distance between two particles and prints out a table containing the distances.  However, when I use the function, nothing is printed. What am I doing wrong?

```
au = 1.49598e11                        #astronomical unit in meters
rx = au * np.asarray([.5,.8,.2])       #x-comp separation vector
ry = au * np.asarray([2.6,9.1,3.7])    #y-comp separation vector
rz = au * np.asarray([.05,.1,.25])     #z-comp separation vector
def svec(x,y,z):
    '''computes the magnitude and vector components of the distance between two particles.'''

    #for loop to compute vector components of separation between two particles
    rvec = []
    for i in range(3):
        if i < 2:
            vx = x[i]-x[i+1]
            vy = y[i]-y[i+1]
            vz = z[i]-z[i+1]
            rvec.append([vx,vy,vz])
         if i == 2:
             vx = x[0]-x[-1]
             vy = y[0]-y[-1]
             vz = z[0]-z[-1]
             rvec.append([vx,vy,vz])
    return rvec
    comp1 = ['x-comp[m]','y-comp[m]','z-comp[m]']
    r0 = rvec[0].insert(0,'particle 0->1')
    r1 = rvec[1].insert(0,'particle 1->2')
    r2 = rvec[2].insert(0,'particle 0->2')
    print(tabulate(rvec,headers=comp1))
```

Comment: Now everything beyond the `return` line will not be executed. Did yuo mean to indent that too?

Comment: Moving everything that was beyond the return line to coming before the return line fixed the issue.  Thank you, Martijn!!!

Answer (score 1):

Python is whitespace sensitive, but docstrings may prevent you from getting a proper error due to your indentation.

Looks like your code should be indented like this:

```
au = 1.49598e11                        #astronomical unit in meters
rx = au * np.asarray([.5,.8,.2])       #x-comp separation vector
ry = au * np.asarray([2.6,9.1,3.7])    #y-comp separation vector
rz = au * np.asarray([.05,.1,.25])     #z-comp separation vector
def svec(x,y,z):
    '''computes the magnitude and vector components of the distance between two particles.'''

    #for loop to compute vector components of separation between two particles
    rvec = []
    for i in range(3):
        if i < 2:
            vx = x[i]-x[i+1]
            vy = y[i]-y[i+1]
            vz = z[i]-z[i+1]
            rvec.append([vx,vy,vz])
        if i == 2:
            vx = x[0]-x[-1]
            vy = y[0]-y[-1]
            vz = z[0]-z[-1]
            rvec.append([vx,vy,vz])
    return rvec

comp1 = ['x-comp[m]','y-comp[m]','z-comp[m]']
r0 = rvec[0].insert(0,'particle 0->1')
r1 = rvec[1].insert(0,'particle 1->2')
r2 = rvec[2].insert(0,'particle 0->2')
print(tabulate(rvec,headers=comp1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The indentation in your code sample seems off: you define a function but the function body is not indented.  Can you make sure that the indentation in the pasted code matches what you're running?

This is important because if your `print` statement comes after the `return` statement in the function, it would explain why nothing is printed.  (Unlike in some other languages, Python will not complain if you have unreachable code after a `return` statement.)  But without seeing the actual indentation in your program, it's impossible for us to say.

EDIT: Now that the indentation has been fixed, I can confirm that the `return` statement will indeed prevent everything after it from being executed.  Perhaps you meant to dedent all of the lines after the return statement?